# Web SQL database in Chrome isn't preserved among tabs and sessions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-sql

When I access my web application in Chrome, it creates a Web SQL Database with the following command:

```
window.openDatabase('dbName', '1.0', 'database', -1);
```

I can immediately see the database listed in Chrome Development Tools -> Resources -> Web SQL and after tables are created and filled with data it all shows properly.

**But** when I reload application or enter it at a different tab, the database isn't listed in Web SQL list. **Why?**

- Per standard the database must persist among tabs and sessions - http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/
- When I try it at a different site, like http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/, all works properly
- I have found where it should be stored on disk - @C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\databases@ in Windows 7. The file is there.

Comment: WebSQL is deprecated and it isn't guaranteed to work any way.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm aware of that. This is a Cordova mobile app relying on sqlite plugin. At development we run it in Chrome with Ripple. So it was natural to use Web SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the reason. My application didn't get to @window.openDatabase@ immediately at load, but rather after specific event. Apparently, Chrome doesn't show databases under Web SQL unless they are opened.

I ran the following command again from Console or caused the event to happen:

```
window.openDatabase('dbName', '1.0', 'database', -1);
```

the database got listed in Development Tools, with all the tables and data as in a different session or tab.

Answer (score -1):

Web SQL is depreciated, but I hope apple and Google keep it for the next 10 years because it is a million times better than that 3rd world attempt at local data storage they call indexDB

Comment: I laughed so hard.